Keeping the Word file formatting into a SharePoint
Dears
Greetings
I am trying to copy a text from a Word file (docx)  into a SharePoint page text field. but the format after I pasted the text is different from the original docx file. any idea how to fix it?
org Docx file

Sharepoint


There seems to be no better way to preserve the style of the text, we can only copy it and adjust it manually.
